# Aes encryption for php crashing my webserver

Tags: php, apache, encryption, aes

for some reason index .php is not working. Here is my code. I was using the example found on http://aesencryption.net/#PHP-aes-encryption-example

```
    <?php
    include 'AES.php's;
    $inputText = "My text to encrypt";
    $inputKey = "My text to encrypt";
    $blockSize = 256;
    $aes = new AES($inputText, $inputKey, $blockSize);
    $enc = $aes->encrypt();
    $aes->setData($enc);
    $dec=$aes->decrypt();
    echo "After encryption: ".$enc."<br/>";
    echo "After decryption: ".$dec."<br/>";
    ?>
```

and for some reason it gives me a 404

Comment: include 'AES.php';

Comment: extra s for sexiness?

Answer (score 0):

In the first line you have used `include 'AES.php's;` change to `include 'AES.php';` I have checked with the example you provided and its working when I changed the wrong syntax

```
<?php
include 'aes.php';
$inputText = "My text to encrypt";
$inputKey = "My text to encrypt";
$blockSize = 256;
$aes = new AES($inputText, $inputKey, $blockSize);
$enc = $aes->encrypt();
$aes->setData($enc);
$dec=$aes->decrypt();
echo "After encryption: ".$enc."<br/>";
echo "After decryption: ".$dec."<br/>";
?>
```

Below is `aes.php` as per your example http://aesencryption.net/#PHP-aes-encryption-example

**aes.php**

```
/**
Aes encryption
*/
class AES {

  const M_CBC = 'cbc';
  const M_CFB = 'cfb';
  const M_ECB = 'ecb';
  const M_NOFB = 'nofb';
  const M_OFB = 'ofb';
  const M_STREAM = 'stream';

  protected $key;
  protected $cipher;
  protected $data;
  protected $mode;
  protected $IV;
/**
* 
* @param type $data
* @param type $key
* @param type $blockSize
* @param type $mode
*/
  function __construct($data = null, $key = null, $blockSize = null, $mode = null) {
    $this->setData($data);
    $this->setKey($key);
    $this->setBlockSize($blockSize);
    $this->setMode($mode);
    $this->setIV("");
  }

/**
* 
* @param type $data
*/
  public function setData($data) {
    $this->data = $data;
  }

/**
* 
* @param type $key
*/
  public function setKey($key) {
    $this->key = $key;
  }

/**
* 
* @param type $blockSize
*/
  public function setBlockSize($blockSize) {
    switch ($blockSize) {
      case 128:
      $this->cipher = MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128;
      break;

      case 192:
      $this->cipher = MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_192;
      break;

      case 256:
      $this->cipher = MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256;
      break;
    }
  }

/**
* 
* @param type $mode
*/
  public function setMode($mode) {
    switch ($mode) {
      case AES::M_CBC:
      $this->mode = MCRYPT_MODE_CBC;
      break;
      case AES::M_CFB:
      $this->mode = MCRYPT_MODE_CFB;
      break;
      case AES::M_ECB:
      $this->mode = MCRYPT_MODE_ECB;
      break;
      case AES::M_NOFB:
      $this->mode = MCRYPT_MODE_NOFB;
      break;
      case AES::M_OFB:
      $this->mode = MCRYPT_MODE_OFB;
      break;
      case AES::M_STREAM:
      $this->mode = MCRYPT_MODE_STREAM;
      break;
      default:
      $this->mode = MCRYPT_MODE_ECB;
      break;
    }
  }

/**
* 
* @return boolean
*/
  public function validateParams() {
    if ($this->data != null &&
        $this->key != null &&
        $this->cipher != null) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return FALSE;
    }
  }

  public function setIV($IV) {
        $this->IV = $IV;
    }
  protected function getIV() {
      if ($this->IV == "") {
        $this->IV = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size($this->cipher, $this->mode), MCRYPT_RAND);
      }
      return $this->IV;
  }

/**
* @return type
* @throws Exception
*/
  public function encrypt() {

    if ($this->validateParams()) {
      return trim(base64_encode(
        mcrypt_encrypt(
          $this->cipher, $this->key, $this->data, $this->mode, $this->getIV())));
    } else {
      throw new Exception('Invlid params!');
    }
  }
/**
* 
* @return type
* @throws Exception
*/
  public function decrypt() {
    if ($this->validateParams()) {
      return trim(mcrypt_decrypt(
        $this->cipher, $this->key, base64_decode($this->data), $this->mode, $this->getIV()));
    } else {
      throw new Exception('Invlid params!');
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks but this dident work for me. where is your AES.php stored?

Comment: @EliasBothell haha.. then what you were doing with the example and what you were trying to included in your code. Any way I edited with the aes.php file which got from the example link

Answer (score 0):

> for some reason index .php is not working.

That's not very helpful.

> I was using the example found on http://aesencryption.net/#PHP-aes-encryption-example

Don't use that code. [Use an well-studied encryption library instead](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/11/choosing-right-cryptography-library-for-your-php-project-guide).